# averaging all rows from Matrix where column 1 has the same value (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, matrix, average, nan

I have a matrix and would like to average all columns where column 1 has the same value. For example
A [1 2 3; 1 2 5; 3 2 5]
The column 1 has two times the number 1, so I would like to all columns where column 1 has number 1, so that the outcome will be
A_new [1 2 4; 3 2 5]

What is the easiest way to do so?

Additionally, I would like in this matrix that every number between 1 and in this example 3, is present in column 1, and that it should fill the corresponding other columns with NaNs.

So the outcome should be
A_new2 [1 2 4; 2 NaN NaN; 3 2 5]

Comment: The same value as what? When you average a "row" of a 3D matrix, do you expect a 1D or a 2D output? How is 150, 152, ... a "missing" value? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with an expected input/output, then all will be clearer. You probably just want something like `mean( A( A(:,1,:) == 150, :, : ), 1 )` but it's impossible to know with this amount of information

Comment: I updated it. Hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html), together with [`findgroups`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) (or [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.unique.html)):

```
A = [1 2 3; 1 2 5; 3 2 5];
[g, h] = findgroups(A(:,1)); % or [~, h, g] = unique(10*A(:,1));
result = [h splitapply(@(x)mean(x,1), A(:, 2:end), findgroups(A(:,1)))];
```